# Unable to access files when executing terminal commands

Tags: swift, macos, shell, terminal, swift4

I am trying to access a file on my computer so I could manipulate it using terminal from within my Swift application. Here is my code:

```
static func getImageText()
{   
    print(NSHomeDirectory())
    let desktop = ""
    shell("pwd")
    shell("cd ~")
    shell("pwd")
    shell("convert \(desktop)hqTriviaMasterTemp.jpg -type Grayscale \(desktop)hqTriviaMasterTemp.tif")
//        shell("convert", "\(desktop)hqTriviaMasterTemp.jpg", "-type Grayscale", "\(desktop)hqTriviaMasterTemp.tif")
//        shell("tesseract", "-l eng", "hqTriviaMasterTemp.jpg", "output")
}

@discardableResult
private static func shell(_ args: String...) -> Int32 {
    let task = Process()
    task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/env"
    task.arguments = args
    task.launch()
    task.waitUntilExit()
    return task.terminationStatus
}
```

When I run the above code, the shell prints the following:

```
/Users/danielsmith
/Users/danielsmith/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HQ_Trivia_Master-daqkzxblkgidgagayyifolcqwtwt/Build/Products/Release
env: cd ~: No such file or directory
/Users/danielsmith/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HQ_Trivia_Master-daqkzxblkgidgagayyifolcqwtwt/Build/Products/Release env: convert hqTriviaMasterTemp.jpg -type Grayscale hqTriviaMasterTemp.tif: No such file or directory
```

The part that is really screwing me up is that I'm not able to cd anywhere, which is preventing me from manipulating the file that I want to manipulate. How do I get cd to work so I can do what I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Terminal, the tilde `~` expansion (to your home directory) is done by the Bash shell *before* running your actual command. But, when using `Process`, all commands are ran directly without going through a shell at all — even when using `"/usr/bin/env"`.

As such, you could try replacing this line:

```
shell("cd ~")
```

with:

```
shell("cd", NSHomeDirectory())
```

But unfortunately this won’t be enough either ;) This only changes the current directory *within* that `Process` instance. Your next command will still run on the previous directory.

What you actually need to do is set the current directory using the `Process.currentDirectoryURL` property:

> If this property isn’t used, the current directory is inherited from the process that created the `Process` object.

For instance:

```
let task = Process()
...
task.currentDirectoryURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSHomeDirectory())
```

and then finally run the desired command.

Comment: While cd isn't giving me an error anymore, the shell is not changing directories.

Comment: Now it says I'm in the correct directory, but when I try to manipulate a file in that directory it says "No such file or directory". It works fine when I call the command through the regular terminal.

Comment: @DaniM.Smith Try running your command like this `shell(“convert”, “foo”, “bar”)` (and not as a single string).

Comment: I tried the following: shell("convert", "hqTriviaMasterTemp.jpg", "-type", "Grayscale", "hqTriviaMasterTemp.tif"). It returned an error code of 127 and printed: env: convert: No such file or directory

Comment: Try using the *full path* to the `convert` utility. To find the absolute path, just run `which convert` in the Terminal.